# Security group allowing traffic from itself

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a **Webserver** in a **VPC** that will occasionally use curl to get or post a resource from itself, using one of the *domains* associated to that `server`.  I have a restrictive security group assigned to this *server*, as I only want to allow `traffic` from specific **IP** *ranges*.  Additionally, I added the security group itself as a source of inbound `traffic`, in order to deal with the curl calls.

Unfortunately this isn't working.  The *connections timeout*.  Using `wget` from *command-line* on the *server's IP* or one of the domains goes timeout too.  The only way to fix it is to allow traffic from '0.0.0.0/0' on the security group, which I don't want to do.

As a workaround I've added '127.0.0.1' entries for every `domain` to the `hosts` file, but this isn't a long term solution for me.

Is any help to fixe?

Answer (score 3):

The traffic is basically going out to the internet and back, which means it is leaving the VPC, so it is no longer identified as coming from within the Security Group. To allow traffic from a Security Group, that traffic has to be addressed to the Private IP address, not the public IP or domain name.

One way to do this is add `hosts` file entries like you have done. You could also create a private hosted zone in Route53 and assign it to the VPC, then override certain DNS records within your VPC to route to the private IP address.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "certain DNS records".  I created a private Route53 zone that forwards to another load balancer but requests still appear like they are from the internet.

Comment: I just meant any DNS records that you want to override inside your VPC.